# how to add onclick method in magento2 admin custom module page?

Tags: magento2, javascript, adminhtml, developer-mode, custom-button

my **edit.php** file in magento admin custom module

```
 $this->addButton(
            'approve',
            [
                'label' => __('Approve'),
                'onclick' => 'deleteConfirm(' . json_encode(__('Are you sure you want to Approve Quote?'))
                    . ','
                    . json_encode($this->getDeleteUrl()
                    )
                    . ')',
                'class' => 'scalable delete',
                'level' => -1
            ]
        );
```

here i want to add my custom method(**Logic**)
how i can add

> 'onclick' => 'deleteConfirm(' . json_encode(__('Are you sure you want
>   to Approve Quote?'))

when add any method shows error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Block\Adminhtml\Managequotes\getDeleteUrl() in
>   /var/www/html/equpo2/app/code/Webkul/Mpquotesystem/Block/Adminhtml/Managequotes/Edit.php
>   on line 57

how i can solve this??

Answer (score 0):

> 'onclick' => 'deleteConfirm(' . json_encode(__('Are you sure you want to Approve Quote?'))

Above code just display text message in popup. so you can not write logic in this line.

And you get fatal error because `getDeleteUrl()` is not exist.

If you want to add custom logic then you have to create controller for that. follow below step.

**Create get URL function**

```
 public function getDeleteUrl()
 {
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/delete', ['id' => $this->getId()]);
 }
```

**Create controller in given path**

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Controller/Index/Delete.php

```
<?php
 namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

 class Delete extends \Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Index
 {
     public function execute()
     {
       //Write your custom logic
     }
 }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: how i add the  controller method 'onclick' => 'deleteConfirm(' . json_encode(__('Are you sure you want to Approve Quote?'))

Comment: when click the button record is deleting why??

Comment: Replace your `onclick` code with this `'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . __(
                    'Are you sure you want to do this?'
                ) . '\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\')'`

Comment: If you write delete record login in controller then it will be delete.

Comment: how the block and controller will merge

Comment: and button is not clickable after added code